# How can one enable keyboard like in iMessages/FB Messenger in landscape mode at iOS8?

Tags: ios, keyboard, ios8, imessage, facebook-messenger

In my project I have textViews with associated input keyboard which has the strange look in **landscape mode on iPhone 6 Plus under iOS8** as shown below:

[image]

It seems that it has different orientation internally sometimes.

But in some cases keyboard rotates fine but still has white gaps during orientation change and other visible bugs:

[image]

and finally we have ordinary expanded landscape view:

[image]

The question is how one can get the extended keyboard without bugs as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The very important thing to do while migrating projects from `xCode5.1` (and earlier) to `xCode6`
is to modify `Info.plist` file by adding `Launch screen interface file base name` key

[image]

You can event set it to empty string (usually it is a name of the `Launch xib`). Without this simply line one will have all the problems presented at screenshots above.

The absence of the `Launch screen interface file base name` results in working in compatibility mode with standard resolution of older devices. Let's run the following code in the project in each case

```
NSLog(@"bounds = %@", NSStringFromCGRect(UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds));
```

With `Launch xib` one gets

```
bounds = {{0, 0}, {414, 736}} // for iPhone 6Plus

bounds = {{0, 0}, {375, 667}} // for iPhone 6
```

Without it one gets

```
bounds = {{0, 0}, {320, 568}}
```

So, the last case indeed is the compatibility mode.

Comment: having a flow like this:
1. portrait screen----enable keyboard----opens keyboard in portrait
2. go to next screen which is landscape----enable keyboard by clicking textfield----opens keyboard in landscape mode.
3. go back to portrait screen-----enable keyboard----opens keyboard in landscape.

what to do...above solution didn't help.

Comment: Its not working for my case also. Please do provide any alternate solution

Answer (score 0):

I found the same kind of problem. When I was allowing only 1 of my  viewcontroller to rotate.As soon as I was going inside the screen I was enabling the screen rotation and while coming out of the screen I was disabling it.Every thing was working fine except the keyboard UI.So I searched many forums for a solution but didn't find out anything useful. Anyhow, I have tried to understand the pattern and found out that I was using viewDidDisappear instead of viewWillDisappear.

Its important to disable the orientation before it goes another screen.Hope this helps.